# How to make code-folding more efficient

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding, performance

I have a ruby file while is about 5K+ lines long.

My current setup uses the [vim-ruby plugin](https://github.com/igbanam/dotfiles/blob/0a369a17feba43c9b8d8f0663ccc028da0288a5d/vimrc#L112).

With this, I [enable code folding](https://github.com/igbanam/dotfiles/blob/0a369a17feba43c9b8d8f0663ccc028da0288a5d/vimrc#L212) with

```
let ruby_fold = 1
```

This opens my ruby files pre-folded. I can open the folds I need to show the file I want to work on. However, while working on the file, when I open a block — like the `do` of the multiline `do ... end`, Vim gets stuck. I'm thinking Vim tries to recalculate the fold lines, and for a file this big, it takes a while.

**Is there anyway to speed this up?**

NB: If I turn off syntax highlighting, editing the file returns to being fast.

Comment: Just realized this isn't an issue when in `nvim`

Comment: Vim’s syntax highlighting is regex based and doesnt do well on huge files. 5k lines is (arguably) too large (even git probably isnt super happy). Can you split it up?

Comment: Try [FastFold](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) in vim.

Comment: There is also a PR on github: [1045](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/1045)